# Using pretty URLs (without index.php) in Laravel application with Apache server

Tags: laravel, apache, url, xampp

### I've tried a lot of google results with this issue but none of them seem to fix it.
I'm running a laravel application with the Alias '/laravel' pointing to my Laravel application.

What works:

```
> localhost/laravel
> localhost/laravel/index.php
> localhost/laravel/index.php/profile/<user>
```

What doesn't work:

```
> localhost/laravel/profile/<user>
```

I just can't get it to work without adding index.php on URLs that are longer than '/', localhost/laravel which points to my *Route::get('/', ...)* works without a hitch.

I'm using the default .htaccess shipped with Laravel.

This is my vhosts cfg:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
ServerName localhost
<Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/LaravelApp/public>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /laravel C:/xampp/htdocs/LaravelApp/public
```

If I set the *DocumentRoot* to Laravel's public folder, it works great. But I can't do this, because I must use localhost root to serve a different file.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you have enable `mod_rewrite` apache module?

Comment: Yes it is enabled

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you deployed your laravel application corretly.
When you deploy, you should put the contents of the "public_html" folder inside the "public" folder in apache webserver and then outside the public folder you can create a folder that contains all the files of your application.
After that you edit the file "index.php" that is inside the public folder and make sure that the path to the files are correct.

With that you dont need to edit .htaccess file.

Comment: I have seperated the /public directory and placed it into the server's public directory, then edited index.php with the correct path to the application. But I still have the same 404 errors on any laravel routes past '/'.